# Check if string includes part of Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci

Which way should I follow to create an algorithm to find out whether fibonacci sequence exists in a given string ?

The string includes only digits with no whitespaces and there may be more than one sequence, I need to find all of them.

Comment: It should be very hard to perform this (if even possible without melting your CPU , at-least i can't think of a way) through brute force.  There might be some cleaver algorithm or mathematical technique to check whether a number is fibonacci or not , but still you'll have to try all the possible combination against that algorithm and that ain't very easy task!These numbers you gave are too big!

Comment: How many items must have, at least, the matchibg seqyence? In your example there are 11 items. Would it be enough just one?

Comment: @UbdusSamad There are some formulas to calculate if a number belongs to fibonacci sequence, also the first index of sequence must be less than 6 digits, so I don't think this operation requires high CPU costs. I am gonna update question.

Comment: @LittleSanti I updated the question.

Comment: How do you asses `1111`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's how I would approach this.

The main algorithm could **search for triplets** then try to extend them to as long a sequence as possible.

This leaves us with the subproblem of finding triplets. So if you are scanning through a string to look for fibonacci numbers, one thing you can take advantage of is that the next number must have the same number of digits or one more digit.

e.g. if you have the string "987159725844" and are considering "[987]159725844" then the next thing you need to look at is "987[159]725844" and "987[1597]25844". Then the next part you would find is "[2584]4" or "[25844]".

Once you have the 3 numbers you can check if they form an arithmetic progression with `C - B == B - A`. If they do you can now check if they are from the fibonacci sequence by seeing if the ratio is roughly 1.6 and then running the fibonacci iteration backwards down to the initial conditions 1,1.

The overall algorithm would then work by scanning through looking for all triples starting with width 1, then width 2, width 3 up to 6.

Comment: As far as I understand, this solution will work. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 4):

If as your comment says the first number must have less than 6 digits, you can simply search for all positions there one of the 25 fibonacci numbers (there are only 25 with less than 6 digits) and than try to expand this 1 number sequence in both directions.

**After your update:**

You can even speed things up when you are only looking for sequences of at least 3 numbers.

Prebuild all 25 3-number-Strings that start with one of the 25 first fibonnaci-numbers this should give much less matches than the search for the single fibonacci-numbers I suggested above.

Than search for them (like described above and try to expand the found 3-number-sequences).

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I can't use look up tables. I have to check if a number belongs to fibonacci by using the formula [ sqrt(5F^2 ± 4) ]

Comment: @ACAkgul: 'I can't use look up tables' Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should first find all interesting Fibonacci items (which, having 6 or less digits, are no more than 30) and store them into an array.

Then, loop every position in your input string, and try to find upon there the **longest** possible Fibonacci number (that is, you must browse the array **backwards**).

If some Fib number is found, then you must bifurcate to a secondary algorithm, consisting of merely going through the array from current position to the end, trying to match every item in the following substring. When the matching ends, you must get back to the main algorithm to keep searching in the input string from the current position.

None of these two algorithms is recursive, nor too expensive.

**update**

Ok. If no tables are allowed, you could still use this approach replacing in the first loop the way to get the bext Fibo number: Instead of indexing, apply your formula.

Comment: I need to find out if a number belongs to fibonacci seq by the formula [ sqrt(5F^2 ± 4) ] so I need to assume I dont have access to Fibo table.